# Is there a way to create a sphere shaped paragraph in powerpoint 2013

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Is there a way to create a sphere shaped paragraph in powerpoint 2013.
Something like this
[image]

Comment: No, there is no such thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an oval and add text to it. This will break the text at the edges of the oval. Next you can apply the warp operation `Inflate` to it.

It's not as nice as your rendered output and would not fit my understanding of aesthetics, but it's "something like this".

[image: Powerpoint screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you see in the text `Warp` dialog is what's available:

[image]

So you'll only be able to warp some lines of text, in some ways. You can always create the sphere in some other program and export it as an image.

<sub>Image [source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/wrap-text-around-a-circle-or-other-shape-HA102849117.aspx)</sub>